# Maintenance Plan job failing with access denied for NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, jobs, maintenance-plans

I used the Maintenance Plan Wizard under SQL Server 2014 to create a simple maintenance plan that once a week:

1. Check Database Integrity including indexes
2. Rebuild Indexes
3. Clean Up History

When the job I get below error message. Any ideas why it is failing? I did check and `NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT` is a member of the sysadmin group as it should be

> Executed as user: NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT. ...2 01:01:31.89
>   Source: Check Database Integrity      Executing query "USE [vc2]  ".:
>   50% complete  End Progress  Error: 2016-05-12 01:01:51.89     Code:
>   0xC002F210     Source: Check Database Integrity Execute SQL Task
>   Description: Executing the query "DBCC CHECKDB(N'vc2')  WITH
>   NO_INFOMSGS  " failed with the following error: "A database snapshot
>   cannot be created because it failed to start.  A database snapshot
>   cannot be created because it failed to start.  CREATE FILE encountered
>   operating system error 5(Access is denied.) while attempting to open
>   or create the physical file 'E:\vc2.mdf_MSSQL_DBCC29'.  The database
>   snapshot for online checks could not be created. Either the reason is
>   given in a previous error or one of the underlying volumes does not
>   support sparse files or alternate streams. Attempting to get exclusive
>   access to run checks offline.  The database could not be exclusively
>   locked to perform the operation.  Check statement aborted. The
>   database could not be checked as a database snapshot could not be
>   created and the database or table could not be locked. See Books
>   Online for details of when this behavior is expected and what
>   workarounds exist. Also see previous errors for more details.".
>   Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet"
>   property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or
>   connection not established correctly.

Comment: It looks to be a permission issue. Make sure your SQL server and SQL agent account has FULL access to E:\ drive on server.

Comment: The process is failing to create snapshot on` E:\ drive` *which is root of drive* , plus it seems like the `SQL Server service account` does not have permission on E drive. Can you check that. I can feel you have created database on root of the folder.